# How to use powershell command get-WindowsUpdateLog to collect application logs only

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, event-log

I'm migrating a project from Windows 7 to Windows 10. The project uses `Wevtutil.exe` to collect system/application logs and it works fine in Windows 7. However, I got recommended to use `get-WindowsUpdateLog` in windows 10 to achieve the same result. Just wondering if there is any difference between `application/system logs` and `Windows update logs`?  I've been searching online but found no answers so far.

In addition, assuming that **Windows update logs** is a super set of **application/system logs**, is it possible to filter through the result of `get-WindowsUpdateLog` and collect only a subset of it (e.g. application logs)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood `Get-WindowsUpdateLog` - it collects and merges Event Trace Log files (`*.etl`) pertaining to Windows Update

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are looking for `Get-EventLog -LogName Application`

Comment: @4c74356b41 I've also had looking into this command. This command seems like having no export flag so I have to use `|` operator if I wish to export the result to a text file?

Comment: yes, you could use that to export data

Comment: @4c74356b41 Cheers mate. Very helpful.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I've just done some reading. Is it correct if I understand ETW as a low level logging mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as per out discussion in the comments, here's what looks to be the answer:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application ... | Out-File path
```

You could also use several other methods to export data and keep it structured (export-csv, export-clixml).
Read more about [Event Tracing for Windows (ETW)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803(v=vs.85).aspx).